# C3P0 Connection Pool in hibernate, still giving me message for when last packet was sent

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

I have the following set up on my hibernate properties xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
            value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"></property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100"></property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="0"></property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
<property name="hiberante.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"></property>
```

Although on my log files I see that my app uses C3P0

```
org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {autoReconnect=true, user=root, password=****}
org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.2.1 [built 20-March-2013 10:47:27 +0000; debug? true; trace: 10]
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@9eef5ffa [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@db682f4d [ acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 2xxc589b1eid2vj1m2f0jg|2ba45490, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 5, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 100, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@4ad0bdd4 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 2xxc589b1eid2vj1m2f0jg|66f66866, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/avalanchedb, properties -> {autoReconnect=true, user=******, password=******} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 2xxc589b1eid2vj1m2f0jg|456abb66, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
```

I tried living my application idle for one day (almost) and tried to use it to store some new entities in the database. I got the following error

```
ERROR  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - The last packet successfully received from the server was 38,491,585 milliseconds ago.
```

Is there a something I must take unser consideration when setting up C3P0?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You need to implement Connection testing.

The simplest thing to do would be to add...

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"></property>
```

...to your config. If you are using a recent c3p0 and a recent JDBC driver that supports an efficient `Connection.isValid(...)` method, that's probably all you need. For deeper discussion of configuring c3p0 Connection testing, see [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing) (and especially the [green box](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing) at the end of the section).

You can resolve this particular issue by simply timing out Connections, rather than testing them...

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge" value="3600"></property>
```

...but you probably want Connection testing anyway. (You can do both as well.)